# How can I find out if a line is an exact match to a line in a text file?

Tags: php, file

A user enters text into a box and that string is compared to a text file line by line for a match. If a match is found do x else z.

This should be easy enough, but I don't know how to do it in php. I found a partial answer, but am not about to finish it out.

```
f = open('filename', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
```

How can I convert this code into php and complete the code?

Comment: Your variables do not have `$`?

Comment: Uh, did you mean `fopen()` ?

Comment: I don't think it is PHP @adeneo

Comment: Yes, fopen is the way I know it, this example was sourced from this site elsewhere.

Comment: @pl3bs Should this be PHP? And also should it be an exact match of the line?

Comment: Who knows, anyway `in_array( 'what', file('filename') )`

Comment: I need it in php, and it should be an exact match of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I read your file into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), where every line is one array element. There I ignore new line characters at the end of each line and also skip empty lines.

Then you can simply do a [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) call to see if the line from the user is in the file.

```
<?php

    $lines = file("yourFile.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    if(in_array($line, $lines)) {
        echo "match do something";
    } else {
        echo "no match do something else";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with `.` and `^$` not matching `line breaks`, i.e.:

```
$file = file_get_contents("file.txt"); //read myfile.txt contents to var $file 
$match = "match 321";
    if (preg_match("/$match/", $file)){ //check if any full line contains "match 321"
        echo "File contains $match";
    }else{
        echo "File doesn't contain $match";
    }
```

Comment: `strpos()` doesn't make sure it's a full line match as apparently the OP wants it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995583/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-line-is-an-exact-match-to-a-line-in-a-text-file/29995648#comment48110754_29995583

Comment: Hi @Rizier123, I've already updated my answer, tks anyway :) Your answer reads the file lines into an array but doesn't loop them,  it's basically the same as read the all file to a single var and use strpos.

Comment: No it's not the same, since my line has to be an exact match to a line in the file. With `strpos()` it can also be only a partial match and could go over 2 lines.

Comment: It's in the comments under OP's question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995583/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-line-is-an-exact-match-to-a-line-in-a-text-file#comment48110754_29995583 *should be an exact match of the line*